# Как мне получить время из VK?

Tags: java, android, вконтакте

С помощью метода wall.get я получаю стену. Как мне получить текст как в вк. Типо 
3 минуты назад. 10 минут назад. и т.д.

Просто там нет такого параметра. Есть только date в формате UTC.

```
long datePost=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        datePost=datePost-Integer.valueOf(arrayDate.get(position));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String d = sdf.format( datePost );
        textDate.setText(d);
```

Comment: Руками, разумеется.

Comment: текущая дата, приведенная к поясу UTC минус дата поста и будет вашими *3 минуты назад*

Answer (score 1):

Очень маловероятно что какой-нибудь сервис будет когда-нибудь возвращать данные подобного рода. Всегда будет возвращаться только время создания записи. Отображение разницы времени создания от текущего времени вам надо реализовать самостоятельно.

Для этого возьмите текущее время устройства и вычтите из него время создания записи. Не забудьте про то, чтобы часовые зоны были идентичными у обоих значений.

Comment: Ничего не работает. Должно быть 25 минут. А получается 05:00

Comment: @Вася, на 1000 делить не надо.Попробуйте наоборот, если ВК секунды отдаёт умножить их на 1000, чтобы получить миллисекунды. И именно их вычитать из системного времени.